# Properly formatting money with two decimal points in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to properly format money to two decimal points in my code.
When I add a quantity of 10 I get a return value of 449.90000000000003.
I would like to see 449.90. Here is the code that I have, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#price').val() * this.value;
    parseFloat(Math.round(tot * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('#total').val(tot);
});

});
</script>  

  </head>
  <body>  
    <table>                        

      <caption>Checkout Time!</caption>                    
      <thead>                        
        <tr>                                                         
          <th>Quantity</th>                                                        
          <th>Total</th>                        
        </tr>                    
      </thead>                                                

      <tbody>                        
        <tr>                                    
            <td><input type="text" id="quantity" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="total" readonly value="44.99"/></td>                        
        </tr>                    
      </tbody>                      

      <tfoot>                        
        <tr>                            
          <td colspan="4" align="right">
          <input type="hidden" id="price" readonly value="44.99" />
            <input type="button" value="Checkout!"/></td>                        
        </tr>                    
      </tfoot>                                    

    </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this code :

```
$('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#price').val() * this.value;
    var new_tot = parseFloat(Math.round(tot * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('#total').val(new_tot);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an assignment for

```
parseFloat(Math.round(tot * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tot = parseFloat(Math.round(tot * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```